# Proofs on equilateral triangles

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

Let $\Delta$ be the set of all triangles with two equal edges and be inscribed in a circle of radius $R$.

So, how do I show that:

Equilateral triangle in $\Delta$ is maximizing the area?

and

this equilateral triangle in $\Delta$ is also maximizing the circumference?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d$=distance from circumcenter to the other side.$$$$
by $AM\geq GM$ $S=\sqrt{R^{2}-d^{2}}(R+d)=\sqrt{(R-d)(R+d)^{3}}\leq\sqrt{27\left(\dfrac{(R-d)+\dfrac{R+d}{3}+\dfrac{R+d}{3}+\dfrac{R+d}{3}}{4}\right)^{4}}$ $$$$
the equality holds when $R-d=\dfrac{R+d}{3}$ $\Longrightarrow$ $R=2d$ $$$$
That is, it's equilateral

Answer (score 2):

Let one of the equal angles be $x$

So, the angles will be $x,x,\pi-2x$

So, using [Law of Sines](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Law_of_Sines), $$\frac a{\sin x}=\frac b{\sin x}=\frac c{\sin(\pi-2x)}=2R$$  where $R$ circum-radius which is constant

So, the sides are $2R\sin x, 2R\sin x, 2R\sin(\pi-2x)=2R\sin2x$

So, the [area](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Triangle_in_Terms_of_Circumradius) will be $$\frac{2R\sin x \cdot  2R\sin x \cdot 2R\sin2x}{4R}=R^22\sin^2x\sin 2x$$

Now, $$2\sin^2x\sin 2x=\cos x\cdot4\sin^3x=\cos x(3\sin x-\sin3x)=\frac{3\cdot 2\sin x\cos x-2\sin3x\cos x}2=\frac{3\sin2x-(\sin4x+\sin2x)}2=\sin2x-\frac{\sin4x}2$$

Using [Second Derivative Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html) prove this will be maximum if $x=\frac\pi3$ as $0<x<\frac\pi2$ as $\pi-2x>0$

Answer (score 0):

If the top angle of such an isosceles triangle is $\alpha$, then the equal sides have lengths $2R\sin\frac{\pi-\alpha}2=2R\cos\frac\alpha2$, the other side has length $4R\cos\frac\alpha2\cdot \sin\frac\alpha2$.
Thus the area is
$$ A = 4R^2\cos^2\frac\alpha2\cdot \sin \alpha$$
and the perimeter is
$$ p = 4R\cos\frac\alpha2\cdot\left(1+ \sin\frac\alpha2\right).$$
Use your favorite technique to find the maxima of these expressions (trigonometric addition formulae may be helpful).